# Best way to save hidden fields from CreateView that have unique_together constraint?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I found a lot of questions and answers on this topic but all of them leave me confused as to what would be the best way to handle this and it seems a lot of aspects have to be considered (e. g. I read about putting the validate_unique() function into the ModelForm but some say it would be unsafe to pass the user to the form)

I want to build a form that users can use to register for an event. The event is derived from the url, the user from the request. Hence I don't actually need it in the form. The issue then is to conduct a check for the together_uniqueness as there can only be one registration per user per event.

Currently my code looks like this:

models.py:

```
class Participant(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["user", "event"], name="user_unique_per_event")]

    user = models.ForeignKey(LocalUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participating = models.BooleanField()
```

forms.py:

```
class EventRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields= ['participating']
```

views.py:

```
class EventRegistrationView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'events/event_registration.html'
    form_class = EventRegistrationForm
    queryset = Event.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.event = Event.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
```

1. What's the best way to implement a check regarding the unique_together constraint?
2. What's the best way to handle an error that would be raised from that check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now figured out a way that seems to work. Maybe it helps somebody as I haven't yet found this exact solution on the web. Would be happy about feedback of course as well ;)

```
class EventRegistrationView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'events/event_registration.html'
    form_class = EventRegistrationForm
    queryset = Event.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.event = Event.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        try:
            form.instance.validate_unique()
        except ValidationError as e:
            from django.forms.utils import ErrorList
            form.add_error(field=None, error=e)
            return super(EventRegistrationView, self).form_invalid(form)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```